# ImportHtml imports only the table header and not the table data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying the import the table from a webpage and i am facing issue.
Import Html imports the headers of the table and not the data. can someone help

IMPORTHTML("https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_analysis/top_gainers_losers.htm","table",0)

Answer (score 1):

So this webpage gets the data for that table after the webpage loads and therefore `IMPORTHTML()` doesn't and can't see it.

**However**, by using the Chrome Network Tool (F12) and reloading the page I found [this](https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_analysis/gainers/niftyGainers1.json) page that serves JSON to fill that table.

Now Google Sheets doesn't have a built-in function to parse JSON but there are scripts out there we can use to create a *custom function*. I have used this [ImportJSON library by bradjasper](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON). The instructions for installing it are on the Github page I linked to.

The resulting sheet function looks like this:

```
=ImportJSON("https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_analysis/gainers/niftyGainers1.json", "/")
```